# How to pass class value from jquery into input box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

**index.php**

```
 <span class="final_build_price" data-from="0" data-to="" data-speed="500" data-refresh-interval="10">0</span>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" id="finalvalue" value="">
    <input type="submit" class="getquote" value="submit" name="send">    
</form>
```

**js**

```
<script>
    $(".dim_price").countTo();
    $(".final_build_price").countTo();
    var finalpice=$(".final_build_price").countTo()
    $('.getquote').click(function(){
        // var fp = JSON.stringfy(finalpice);
        var fp =parseInt(finalpice);
        alert(fp);
        // document.getElementById("final_price").innerHTML=fp;
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(".dim_price").countTo();
    var finalpice=$(".final_build_price").countTo()
    $('.getquote').click(function(){
        // var fp = JSON.stringfy(finalpice);
        var fp =parseInt(finalpice);
        alert(fp);
        document.getElementById("final_price").innerHTML=fp;
    });
</script>
```

In span class(final_build_price) i am getting a value from below mention jquery but I want to pass that value into input box on click on submit button and the javascript code i used is mentioned below. but I am not getting any data into input box

Comment: Check the value you are getting in var finalprice. using console.log

Comment: it's giving output is NAN

Comment: I guess you are doing it wrong, try accessing the value of your class using .html or .text() Eg : $(".final_build_price").html()

Comment: we cannot test this as you are using a plugin. Please make a working code snippet that reproduces your current situation.

Comment: You don’t appear to have any element with the ID `final_price` there - you have `finalvalue` instead. And the value of an input field is set by assigning it to the `value` property, or using `.val()` in jQuery, not innerHTML or .html() or anything like that.

Comment: output is [object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is due to write **id** in place to **class** and name of your element.

replace

> document.getElementById("final_price").innerHTML=fp;

by

> $(".final_build_price").html(fp);